# matching and appending strings to headers

Tags: awk, sed, fasta

I want to append strings to sequence headers in a FASTA file.

### Input:

```
>uce-101_seqname
GGCTGGCACCAGTTAACTTGGGATATTGGAGTGAAAAGGCCCGTAATCAGCCTTCGGTCATGTAGAACAATGCATAAAATTAAATTGACATTAATGAATAATTGTGTAATGAAAATGGA
```

### Desired output:

```
>uce-101_seqname |uce-101
GGCTGGCACCAGTTAACTTGGGATATTGGAGTGAAAAGGCCCGTAATCAGCCTTCGGTCATGTAGAACAATGCATAAAATTAAATTGACATTAATGAATAATTGTGTAATGAAAATGGA
```

### Example code:

```
awk -F ">" '{if($2 ~ /^uce/){print $0 " |" substr($2,1,7)} else {print $0}}' <inputfile>
```

The example code only works for 7 characters (e.g., uce-101). I need it to work for greater and less than 7 characters (e.g., uce-1, uce-10, uce-1001).

Comment: try deleting the part you don't want `sub(/_seqname/,"", $2); print ...` plus your code that creates the "|uce-101".  Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do:

```
awk -F">|_" 'NF>2 {$0=$0" |"$2}1' file
>uce-101_seqname |uce-101
GGCTGGCACCAGTTAACTTGGGATATTGGAGTGAAAAGGCCCGTAATCAGCCTTCGGTCATGTAGAACAATGCATAAAATTAAATTGACATTAATGAATAATTGTGTAATGAAAATGGA
```

Set field separator to `>` or `_`
If line contains more than two field, recreate the line
Print all lines.

If you need to test for `uce`, then this should do:

```
awk -F">|_" '$2~/^uce/ {$0=$0" |"$2}1' file
```

Comment: This should do: `awk -F">|_" 'NF>2 {name=$2}{print >name}'` file.  Can you upvote my post, some has give minus without telling why.

Answer (score 3):

I think [shellter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/620097/shellter) has hit the nail on the head with his comment above. With that, your line of [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) could be reduced to:

```
awk -F '>' '$2~/^uce/ { x=$2; sub(/_.*/,"",x); print $0, "|" x; next }1' file
```

Results:

```
>uce-101_seqname |uce-101
GGCTGGCACCAGTTAACTTGGGATATTGGAGTGAAAAGGCCCGTAATCAGCCTTCGGTCATGTAGAACAATGCATAAAATTAAATTGACATTAATGAATAATTGTGTAATGAAAATGGA
```

---

However, if you'd prefer a [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) solution, you could try:

```
sed '/^>uce/s/>\([^_]*\).*/& |\1/' file
```

Results:

```
>uce-101_seqname |uce-101
GGCTGGCACCAGTTAACTTGGGATATTGGAGTGAAAAGGCCCGTAATCAGCCTTCGGTCATGTAGAACAATGCATAAAATTAAATTGACATTAATGAATAATTGTGTAATGAAAATGGA
```

Explanation:

```
/^>uce/      # This is an address that specifies which lines are to be
             # examined or modified. In this case, only lines beginning
             # the string 'uce' are to be addressed.

s/../../     # Perform a substitution using the '/' delimiter

>\([^_]*\).* # This is the pattern to be matched. The '>' character is a
             # literal '>'. Escaped parentheses are then used to capture
             # a character class that says any character not an
             # underscore any (zero or more) number of times. All this
             # is then followed by any character any number of times.

& |\1        # This is the replacement string. The '&' character is the
             # whole pattern that was found. This is followed by a
             # literal space and a literal pipe character. '\1' is then
             # our pattern that we kept using our escaped parentheses.
```

Comment: The sed solution might also be `sed 's/^>\(uce-[^_]*\).*/& | \1/' file`